# How do I return the difference between the current date and each query result date?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to get the difference between the current `date_time` and the `date_time` of each query record. I've tried:

```
matches = session.query((datetime.now() - Match.date_time_inferred).label("time_diff"))
```

But I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Philip\Miniconda3\envs\capra\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3149, in __getitem__
    def __getitem__(self, item):
  File "C:\Users\Philip\Miniconda3\envs\capra\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3149, in __getitem__
    def __getitem__(self, item):
  File "C:\Users\Philip\Miniconda3\envs\capra\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 35, in instances
    def instances(query, cursor, context):
  File "C:\Users\Philip\Miniconda3\envs\capra\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 62, in __exit__
    def __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback):
  File "C:\Users\Philip\Miniconda3\envs\capra\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 148, in raise_
    def raise_(
  File "C:\Users\Philip\Miniconda3\envs\capra\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 35, in instances
    def instances(query, cursor, context):
  File "C:\Users\Philip\Miniconda3\envs\capra\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 84, in <listcomp>
    keyed_tuple([proc(row) for proc in process])
  File "C:\Users\Philip\Miniconda3\envs\capra\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 84, in <listcomp>
    keyed_tuple([proc(row) for proc in process])
  File "C:\Users\Philip\Miniconda3\envs\capra\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\sqltypes.py", line 1952, in process
    def process(value):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Where is the float coming from? `Table1.date_time` is definitely a `date_time` field...

Comment: Ah ok. So the query is trying to return a `date_time` field which is what `Match.date_time_inferred` is?

Comment: That's the only minus sign. Must be. Have you tried looking at the type or value of its operands in the debugger?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do this or even what I'm looking for I'm afraid. When I look at `matches[0]` then it is a tuple of a single `None`)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use SQL functions for that. For example, for PostgreSQL, it would be

```py
matches = session.query((func.now() - Match.date_time_inferred).label("time_diff"))
```

Then it only gets processed when it's at the database level, but you shouldn't get problems with values being the wrong type.

Comment: Thanks! What would I do if I wanted to use a `date_time` object in place of the `datetime.now()`?

Comment: You should be able to just insert it, or you can turn it into a string and insert it like that

Comment: Hi. Tried inserting but same error :( Converting to a string gets data in but it looks like it then converts `Match.date_time_inferred` into an integer based on the string representation of the date, e.g. 1990-01-01 becomes 199001010000000. Is it just me or is this not something that would be a common task?